# How to avoid disappearing the cell seperator when click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have done cell expanding when click on the cell in this way.

in `didSelectRowatIndex`

```
self.tblPlaylist.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
self.tblPlaylist.separatorColor=UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.3)

// avoid paint the cell is the index is outside the bounds
if self.selectedRowIndex != -1 {
    self.tblPlaylist.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.selectedRowIndex, inSection: 0))?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

if selectedRowIndex != indexPath.row {
    self.thereIsCellTapped = true
    self.selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
}
else {
    // there is no cell selected anymore
    self.thereIsCellTapped = false
    self.selectedRowIndex = -1
}

self.tblPlaylist.beginUpdates()
self.tblPlaylist.endUpdates()
```

in heightForrowAtIndex method

```
if (indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex && thereIsCellTapped) {
    return 100
}
return 70
```

Cell expanding happens. But my problem is when I tap a cell,, the seperator above it is dissappearing. Then If I tapped that above cell to the currently tapped cell or any other than cell that seperator loads again. How I can stop this disappearing the cell seperator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the default separator. Create an UIView inside your cell with the proper constraints and you won't have any issues like that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made a custom line for a seperator. But when my cell expands it remains in the same position. Where do I need to change it's frame? In which delegate. when cell expands my line should be increased its Y when shrink,, Y should be reduced

Comment: You either use autolayout and set a bottom constraint or override '-layoutSubviews' method and set the frame of the separator.